# An analogy to describe an individual who merges traits he finds from others in order to develop his own identity?

Tags: analogy, metaphors, comparisons

I am writing a research paper in which my thesis concerns how a character matures through his merging of characteristic traits in his relationships with other characters. How can I introduce this topic with an analogy "attention-getter" that demonstrates this idea of merging things together to form something new?

In another words, I'm looking for an analogy that compares how an individual who combines attributes that he acquires from his relationships can actually create a new, and better, identity for himself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for - an individual to takes the best from everything (what does that mean?), or an analogy that demonstrates the idea of merging things together to form something new?  Can you give us some examples that may help make your request clearer?

Comment: This sounds like you're looking for a technical term. Either one that exists already or a new one for a concept that you're creating for your thesis. 'chameleon' fits your description but has a negative connotation.

Comment: it is impossible to observe the quantum without influencing it.

Comment: Chameleon has a negative connotation? I would have thought it perfect for this. Well except that I'm not actually sure what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the concept of a [Chimera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_%28mythology%29) as the basis for your analogy. The idea being that it is a composite creature that combines the best traits of the creatures that make it up.

Comment: Thank you! That is a wonderful suggestion and it does have a neutral connotation that I can use to my advantage.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there isn't a negative connotation to the term. So, something like, "He was like an emotional chimera, incorporating the best qualities from those around him to improve himself."

Comment: Unfortunately, _chimera_ already has an established figurative meaning, “anything perceived as wildly imaginative or implausible.” It's often used like _hobgoblin_ to mean something unnecessarily frightening. I'm afraid that this established meaning would cause confusion in your context. _Chameleon_ is more commonly used in that sense.

Answer (score 3):

Cloner?

Assimilator?

Could you use the analogy of a harlequin-like personality, in which the traits are patched together from a range of different fabrics to form a garment which is assumed, but is not qualitatively part of the essence of the person?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an analogy from the bible:

> Therefore every scribe which is instructed unto the kingdom of heaven
>   is like unto a man that is an householder, which bringeth forth out of
>   his treasure things new and old. (Mt 13:52)